# Similar dict structures to a final structure for wrinting a parser

Tags: python, dictionary, structure

I have to write a parser. All xml files i received are converted to python dicts (about 10k). Now they share the basic structure, but many of them have some different sub-structures. How can i read all keys from all dicts and combine them to one final structure to have an overview which keys exist? They are a combination of dict, array, str and i tried:

```
for x in dict.keys():
    print(x)
```

But how to combine them to one final overview of all keys of all dicts?

Comment: Can you share example of input data and example of what are you expecting?

Comment: Oooversimiplified example:

A:

{'id' : 'asdf',
 'title' : 'jkl'}

B:

{'id' : 'asdf',
 'title' : 'jkl',
 'products': [{'value': 'brush'}]}

Combine them to C:

{'id' : 'asdf',
 'title' : 'jkl',
 'products': [{'value': 'brush'}]}



I dont care what happens to the values, if they are overwritten etc, i just care about the keys... i want to see a final structure of all keys that CAN exist in these 10k dicts

In other words, i want one final structure populated by all keys of these 10k dicts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have following dicts:

```
a = {'id': 'asdf', 'title': 'jkl'}
b = {'id': 'asdf', 'title': 'jkl', 'products': [{'value': 'brush'}]}
```

You can merge them following way:

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z

print(merge_two_dicts(a, b))
>>> 'id': 'asdf', 'title': 'jkl', 'products': [{'value': 'brush'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around more than a little bit and got it working, its a combination of python+linux, but with a little programming it could be python only. If anyone is interested and having the same problem here is my code, if you have improvements, please answer it as i am very interested:

```
def build_summary_dict(indicator, number, before_key):
    if type(indicator) is dict:
        for key in indicator.keys():
            if len(before_key) < 1:
                print(key)
                build_summary_dict(indicator[key], number+1, key)
            else:
                print('    '*number + before_key + ':' + key)
                build_summary_dict(indicator[key], number+1, before_key + ':' + key)
    if type(indicator) is list:
        for i in indicator:
            build_summary_dict(i, number, before_key + '[]')
```

My only output comes from this command and then i execute in linux:

```
python3.6 myprogram.py | sort | uniq
```

now i got a list of everything i wanted, without this i would have overseen many things when parsing

you can run this this without the sort and uniq to get the output of each single individual element

kind regards